# Clarification of Shabat's proof of Hartogs' lemma

Tags: cv.complex-variables, several-complex-variables

I posted the question on math stackexchange, but my earlier questions there on SCV got no responses, so maybe I'll get some input here.
I have trouble with understanding Shabat's proof of Hartogs' Lemma, used in a proof of Hartog's theorem.
Let $U(a,r)$ denote polydisc centered at $a$ with radii $r$, $'z=(z_1,...,z_{n-1})\in\mathbb{C}^{n-1}$, $'0=(0,...,0)\in\mathbb{C}^{n-1}$, $'V=U('0,R), 'W=('0,r), 0<r<R, U_n=\{|z_n|<R\},V='V\times U_n,W='W\times U_n$. 
Let $f('z,z_n)$ be holomorphic in $\overline{'V}$ with respect to $'z$ for every $z_n\in\overline{U_n}$ and holomorphic with respect to $z=('z,z_n)\in\mathbb{C}^n$ in $\overline W$.

For every $z_n\in U_n$ and $'z\in\,'V$ $f$ can be represented as a convergent multiple power series 
$$f(z)=\sum_{|k|=0}^\infty c_k(z_n)('z)^k$$
where $k=(k_1,...,k_n), |k|=k_1+...+k_n,\,'z^k=z_1^{k_1}\cdots z_{n-1}^{k_{n-1}}$.
Shabat claims that the coefficients $$c_k(z_n)=\frac1{k!}\frac{\partial^{|k|}f('0,z_n)}{(\partial\,'z)^k}$$ are holomorphic in $U_n$ as derivatives of a holomorphic function wrt $z_n$.
I fail to see why. We differentiate wrt $'z$, $f('z,z_n)$ is holomorphic in $'V$ with $z_n$ fixed, I don't see how to obtain holomorphy of $c_k(z_n)$ in $U_n$.

Comment: It's very simple: points $('0,z_n)$ are in $W$, where $f$ is holomorphic, so the partial derivatives are holomorphic as well.